# Problems with Overleaf compiling all my code

Tags: overleaf

I have the following overleaf file, it runs when the postulates and proposition files are there, but when I add the definition file it only prints that file (and they all print fine the themselves).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{enumerate}

% Standard packages
\usepackage{
    float, 
    graphicx
}

% Set page margins
\usepackage[top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, left=1.0in, right=1.0in]{geometry}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}

% Set nice page headers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Paragraph style
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}


% Proposition environment
\newenvironment{proposition}
    {\begin{center}\em}
    {\end{center}}

%Diagram enviroment    
\newenvironment{diagram}
{\begin{center}\vspace*{10pt}\begin{tikzpicture}}
    {\end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{-5pt}\end{center}}
 
 
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt}{0pt}{30pt}

\titleformat{\section}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{-20pt}{\Large}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}

\title{Euclid's \textit{Elements}}
\author{Joe Blogs}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Definitions}
\input{Chapter/Definitions}

\chapter{Postulates}
\input{Chapter/Postulates}

\chapter{Propositions}
\input{Chapter/Propostions}


\end{document}
```

I realise people won't be able to compile this as I have not attached the files, I was just wondering if I am doing something silly, first time overleaf user. Or is there a better place to post this question. Thanks

Comment: It will help if you provide a self-contained example with code everyone can compile. If latex stops on Definitions, it's likely there are errors. Have you checked the log?

Comment: either errors or your `definition` file has `\end{document}` but show the log from the above

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought it would be something silly and it was the \end{document} mistake I feel a fool, but its the way I learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common cause of premature ending of a document is a rogue `\end{document}` in a included file.